# Delete from SQL Server database

Tags: c#, database, linq-to-sql

I'm using a SQL Server database in my program with Linq-to-SQL

I'm using this code to empty the database

```
 db.Tb1.DeleteAllOnSubmit(db.Tb1.Select(x => x));
 db.SubmitChanges();
```

After executing this code, everything in the database will be cleared out. But the problem is the size of database didn't decrease when the rows deleted.

I mean the size of database is still the same after I use that code when it has no data

Sorry for bad English

Comment: it will if you only have one table in your only have one table Tb1 in your db

Comment: if i create another table in the DB this problem will resolved ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how SQL Server works. The space isn't returned unless you manually run a "Free unused space" operation on the database, which re-organizes how the records are physically stored in your database file. Otherwise the unused space is kept and reused as new records are added.

Comment: Please notice that shrinking a database causes crazy amounts of fragmentation.

Comment: my database is attached , how can i free unused space on the DB

Comment: @Asem: that's a messy kludgy mechanism - with an "attached" database, there's a lot of things you cannot do. I would recommend attaching your database to the SQL Server instance you already have on your machine, and use it that way - then you can do these kind of things....

Answer (score 2):

The database doesn't shrink its data files whenever rows are deleted. You have to ask the server to shrink its files, for instance with the T-SQL command `DBCC SHRINKDATABASE` (see [MSDN Documentation for DBCC SHRINKDATABASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190488.aspx)). Main reason for this behavior is probably the performance impact of a shrink. In addition, the server will reuse the now free pages. For databases that regularly delete large sets of rows or truncate complete tables you can schedule the shrinking as a maintenance task. You should then in addition schedule an update of your database statistics (T-SQL command `UPDATE STATISTICS`) for that table.